# Select the last logged change before a specified time from a change list

Tags: mysql, join, timestamp

I want to get the last change for all issues issue, that was made before a specified end time. I have 3 tables.

projects

```
+---+------------+
|ID |project_key |
+---+------------+
|1  |bug_tracker |
+---+------------+
```

issues

```
+---+------------+-------------+
|ID |project_key |issue_key    |
+---+------------+-------------+
|1  |bug_tracker |bug_tracker-1|
+---+------------+-------------+
|2  |bug_tracker |bug_tracker-2|
+---+------------+-------------+
|3  |bug_tracker |bug_tracker-3|
+---+------------+-------------+
```

issue_changes

```
+---+--------------------+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+
|ID |change_by           |change_time |issue_key |change_field |change_value    |
+---+--------------------+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+
|1  |johny_vegas         |1346422320  |1         |Status       |Created         |
|2  |edward_scissorhands |1346497920  |1         |Status       |Open            |
|3  |harry_potter        |1346546460  |1         |Status       |Resolved        |
|4  |harry_potter        |1346682780  |1         |Status       |Closed          |
|5  |harry_potter        |1346252021  |2         |Status       |Created         |
|6  |harry_potter        |1346252023  |2         |Status       |Open            |
|7  |cmdr_data           |1346338440  |2         |Status       |Owned           |
|8  |luke_skywalker      |1346404980  |2         |Status       |Resolved        |
|9  |johny_rico          |1346419560  |2         |Status       |Open            |
|10 |johny_rico          |1346419560  |2         |Status       |Waive Requested |
|11 |edward_scissorhands |1346433300  |2         |Status       |Open            |
|12 |edward_scissorhands |1346433300  |2         |Status       |Waive Requested |
|13 |edward_scissorhands |1346433300  |2         |Status       |Waived          |
|14 |roger_rabit         |1346252052  |3         |Status       |Created         |
|15 |roger_rabit         |1346252054  |3         |Status       |Open            |
|16 |roger_rabit         |1346255700  |3         |Status       |Owned           |
|17 |cmdr_data           |1346261220  |3         |Status       |Resolved        |
|18 |luke_skywalker      |1346405040  |3         |Status       |Open            |
|19 |johny_vegas         |1346423460  |3         |Status       |Owned           |
+---+--------------------+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+
```

Now what I expect to get as the result of a query is:

```
+---+--------------------+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+
|ID |change_by           |change_time |issue_key |change_field |change_value    |
+---+--------------------+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+
|4  |harry_potter        |1346682780  |1         |Status       |Closed          |
|13 |edward_scissorhands |1346433300  |2         |Status       |Waived          |
|19 |johny_vegas         |1346423460  |3         |Status       |Owned           |
+---+--------------------+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+
```

What I am able to get back is:

```
+---+--------------------+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+
|ID |change_by           |change_time |issue_key |change_field |change_value    |
+---+--------------------+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+
|1  |johny_vegas         |1346422320  |1         |Status       |Created         |
|5  |harry_potter        |1346252021  |2         |Status       |Created         |
|14 |roger_rabit         |1346252052  |3         |Status       |Created         |
+---+--------------------+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+
```

The query that I am using is:

```
SELECT issue1.`issue_key` , changes1.`change_time` , changes1.`change_value` , changes1.`change_field` 
FROM  `issue_changes` AS changes1
INNER JOIN  `issues` AS issue1 ON issue1.`ID` = changes1.`issue_key` 
WHERE issue1.`project_key` =  "bug_tracker"
AND changes1.`change_field` =  "Status"
AND changes1.`change_time` <  "1400110321"
GROUP BY issue1.`issue_key`
ORDER BY changes1.`issue_key` , changes1.`change_time` DESC
```

What am I missing? :)

Comment: You're missing DDL and DML so that people can try the query! Give us the tables and how to populate them in the form of SQL scripts, either here or, for example, on SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PROPOSED QUERY

```
SELECT B.* FROM
(SELECT MAX(changes1.ID) ID,changes1.issue_key
FROM  `issue_changes` AS changes1
INNER JOIN  `issues` AS issue1 ON issue1.`ID` = changes1.`issue_key` 
WHERE issue1.`project_key` =  "bug_tracker"
AND changes1.`change_field` =  "Status"
AND changes1.`change_time` <  "1400110321"
GROUP BY changes1.issue_key) A
LEFT JOIN issue_changes B USING (ID);
```

## SAMPLE DATA

```
drop database if exists jamie;
create database jamie;
use jamie
```

## projects

```
create table projects
(
    ID int not null auto_increment,
    project_key varchar(32),
    primary key (ID)
);
insert into projects (project_key) values ('bug_tracker');
```

## issues

```
create table issues
(
    ID int not null auto_increment,
    project_key varchar(32),
    issue_key varchar(32),
    primary key (ID),
    KEY (project_key)
);
insert into issues (project_key,issue_key) values
('bug_tracker','bug_tracker-1'),
('bug_tracker','bug_tracker-2'),
('bug_tracker','bug_tracker-3');
```

## issue_changes

```
create table issue_changes
(
    ID int not null auto_increment,
    change_by    varchar(32),
    change_time  bigint not null,
    issue_key    int not null,
    change_field varchar(32),
    change_value varchar(32),
    primary key (ID)
);
insert into issue_changes
(change_by,change_time,issue_key,change_field,change_value) values
('johny_vegas'        ,1346422320,1,'Status','Created         '),
('edward_scissorhands',1346497920,1,'Status','Open            '),
('harry_potter'       ,1346546460,1,'Status','Resolved        '),
('harry_potter'       ,1346682780,1,'Status','Closed          '),
('harry_potter'       ,1346252021,2,'Status','Created         '),
('harry_potter'       ,1346252023,2,'Status','Open            '),
('cmdr_data'          ,1346338440,2,'Status','Owned           '),
('luke_skywalker'     ,1346404980,2,'Status','Resolved        '),
('johny_rico'         ,1346419560,2,'Status','Open            '),
('johny_rico'         ,1346419560,2,'Status','Waive Requested '),
('edward_scissorhands',1346433300,2,'Status','Open            '),
('edward_scissorhands',1346433300,2,'Status','Waive Requested '),
('edward_scissorhands',1346433300,2,'Status','Waived          '),
('roger_rabit'        ,1346252052,3,'Status','Created         '),
('roger_rabit'        ,1346252054,3,'Status','Open            '),
('roger_rabit'        ,1346255700,3,'Status','Owned           '),
('cmdr_data'          ,1346261220,3,'Status','Resolved        '),
('luke_skywalker'     ,1346405040,3,'Status','Open            '),
('johny_vegas'        ,1346423460,3,'Status','Owned           ');
```

## PROPOSED QUERY EXECUTED

```
mysql> SELECT B.* FROM
    -> (SELECT MAX(changes1.ID) ID,changes1.issue_key
    -> FROM  `issue_changes` AS changes1
    -> INNER JOIN  `issues` AS issue1 ON issue1.`ID` = changes1.`issue_key`
    -> WHERE issue1.`project_key` =  "bug_tracker"
    -> AND changes1.`change_field` =  "Status"
    -> AND changes1.`change_time` <  "1400110321"
    -> GROUP BY changes1.issue_key) A
    -> LEFT JOIN issue_changes B USING (ID);
+------+---------------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
| ID   | change_by           | change_time | issue_key | change_field | change_value     |
+------+---------------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
|    4 | harry_potter        |  1346682780 |         1 | Status       | Closed           |
|   13 | edward_scissorhands |  1346433300 |         2 | Status       | Waived           |
|   19 | johny_vegas         |  1346423460 |         3 | Status       | Owned            |
+------+---------------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## EPILOGUE

The main part of the query is the subquery because it retrieves the maximum ID for each issue_key

```
SELECT MAX(changes1.ID) ID,changes1.issue_key
FROM  `issue_changes` AS changes1
INNER JOIN  `issues` AS issue1 ON issue1.`ID` = changes1.`issue_key` 
WHERE issue1.`project_key` =  "bug_tracker"
AND changes1.`change_field` =  "Status"
AND changes1.`change_time` <  "1400110321"
GROUP BY changes1.issue_key
```

Then, I take the result of the subquery and `LEFT JOIN` the `ID` to `issue_changes`

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Fantastic Rolando. That query works a real treat! :)